# banned from chat?

Tags: support, status-norepro, chat

Okay, this is weird and somewhat disconcerting - for the past few hours, I have not been able to access the Periodic Table (as in enter it, I can see it though).

The last message to me from a room owner was to not ping him as he was "sleeping", which I could not have known, and I only pinged him in a greeting as I saw his avatar enter the room.

There was no warning of a ban if this is one.

Comment: You're not suspended in chat or anything else, this is probably a technical issue. Try refreshing any caches you can think of.

Comment: That *is* disturbing. Do you get a warning message San? Try Dev tools and see what error you get.

Comment: @Sant more importantly, can you reach the transcript or is the whole domain out?

Comment: I'll have to check later - have an emergency to attend to...

Comment: Retracted close vote, but you didn't need to act like this. Two mods told you and I'm telling you now: You were **not** banned anywhere for any cause.

Comment: Hey, don't ban @san. It's nice to have him around. I don't know if it is a tech issue or else, but at least mods do something to get san live. 
Thank you.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M sorry, I find it hard to believe due to [Martin begged me to unban you. And I'm merciful](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24104114#24104114) in chat. Having said that, this is not the sole reason (and don't assume otherwise), but this and the fact that I am now in a very serious illness - and other things (mostly positive) - it is the 'last straw' and honestly, I am tired and are going to focus on more consistently positive activities.

Comment: That was a joke, and I believe not the first one you've seen from me. I still don't understand this misunderstanding. @Did see MadSci's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Moderators can see all previous suspensions on a chat user as well as any times a room owner kicked a particular user. All of these events are logged and visible to any diamond moderator in chat.

I can see this information as I'm a moderator in chat, and your account was never suspended and was never kicked out of any chat room. So this must have been a technical issue, no moderator or room owner intentionally banned you.